# Python- Armstrong Number

Tags: python

```
# Armstrong Number
num= int(input("Enter a number: "))
a=[]
b=[]
while num>0:
  digit=num%10   #Taking the last digit
  a.append(digit) # creating a list with the individual digits
  num=num//10

for i in a:
  numb=i**len(a) #Calculating the power
  b.append(numb) # Creating a new list with the numbers powered to length of the digits

summ=sum(b)      #Sum of all the digits in the new list "b"
print("Sum is:", summ)

if summ == num:
  print("Yes Armstrong No")
else:
  print("Not Armstrong")
```

The last summ==num "if" condition is always returning the else condition.

Eg if my number (num) is 371, then 3^3+7^3+1^3 is also 371 which is original number = sum and hence it's an Armstrong number so it should return "Yes Armstrong No" but it returning "No" (else condition)..I am unable to identify the error as summ==num (is true here).

Comment: Because you are overwriting `num`. Printing its values before `if sum == num` gave me `0`. So you should save the input value in another variable.

Comment: Num is always 0, what are you trying to achieve with that comparison?

Answer (score 0):

You should make a copy of your original input:

```
original_num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
num = original_num
```

... and check that instead, as you overwrite `num` a few times:

```py
if summ == original_num:
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the number.

You can just write:

```
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
sum = 0

if num > 0:
  for digit in str(num):
    sum += int(digit)**len(str(num))

if sum == num:
  print("Yes Armstrong No")
else:
  print("Not Armstrong")
```

And it will work.

Comment: What is `num` ?

Comment: Suggest - don't use the built-in ```sum``` as the variable name.  ```total``` eg. is better...

Comment: yes I never use it but I uploaded the code fast XD

Comment: Fails with ValueError exception if user input is not a positive integer

Comment: An Amstrong number can't be negative because an Armstrong number is a digit which is the total of its digits raised to the third power equals the number itself. Since the number is equated with summation (which can never be negative), an Armstrong number can’t be negative

Comment: I updated the code for negative numbers anyways